# Unable to add a record because of dynamicproxy issue with c# and linq

Tags: c#, linq

I'm calling the following function below at various places.  Basically, I have a list - UserList, that is filled with UserListItems.  In this situation, it is a hardcoded "Managers" List.  I can create the manager's list fine, but I need to run this process to ensure everything is up to date.  Have any managers been added, deleted, etc.  So I first build a list of who the managers are from the Member table(this is up to date).  I then get a list of managers saved within the UserList table.  The foreach below is supposed to see if the Member table has additional managers than within the UserList.  If there are additional ones, they should be added as userlistitems.  My issue is that when I get to save changes, I'm given the following error:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.ApplicationUser...' to type
>   'System.String'.

the UserListItem table is only a relationship table and has the fields

- UserListItemId
- UserListId
- UserId

and both the userId and UserListId seem to be correct when debugging.  What am I missing?

```
    public void UpdateManagerList()
    {
        var member = GetUserMember();

        var managerList = db.UserList.Where(u => u.Name == "Managers" && u.OrgId == member.OrgId).FirstOrDefault();
        var listId = managerList.O_UserListId;

        // list and user ids for up to date managers.
        List<O_Member> ManagersCur = db.O_MemberWhere(u => u.OrgId == member.OrgId && u.Manage == true && u.JoinedStored == true).ToList();
        List<string> curUserIds = ManagersCur.Select(u => u.UserId).ToList();

        //list of managers stored in userlist
        List<UserListItem> ManagersList = db.UserListItem.Where(u => u.UserListId == listId).ToList();
        List<string> listUserIds = ManagersList.Select(u => u.UserId).ToList();

        foreach (var item in ManagersCur) 
        {
            var mUser = ManagersList.Where(u => listUserIds.Contains(item.UserId)).FirstOrDefault();
            if (mUser != null)
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                string userId = item.UserId;
                UserListItem newUser = new UserListItem();
                newUser.UserListId = listId;
                newUser.UserId = userId;
                db.UserListItem.Add(newUser);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your mUser query seems very funny to me - your where condition has no dependency on u, so why wouldn't you just test for `listUserIds.Contains(item.UserId)`  e.g. make your test `if (!listUserIds.Contains(item.UserId))` then add UserListItem.

Comment: Also, why are you doing the `.Include(o => i.UserList)` - presumably, that is the data you already know and stored in managerList?

Comment: And should you be removing managers on the list that are no longer assigned as managers for any user?

Comment: thanks netmags, I'll check out the query.  I realize the include was unnecessary, but I was testing things and forgot to take it out.  Also, the removal of managers will happen in another foreach, but I took it out for simplicity with this issue.

Comment: Your first suggestion if (!listUserIds.Contains(item.UserId)) oddly enough gets me through the first record, but then I get the same error as above on the 2nd record.  What could be causing this?  Just driving me crazy.  Thanks for the help

Comment: It seems like it had something to do with my cache or with my entity state.  I was having an issue with the logged in user and adding - db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Detached; resolved my issue.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps cleaning up your code would help?

```
public void UpdateManagerList() {
    var member = GetUserMember();

    var managerList = db.UserList.Where(u => u.Name == "Managers" && u.OrgId == member.OrgId).FirstOrDefault();
    var listId = managerList.O_UserListId;

    // list and user ids for up to date managers.
    List<O_Member> ManagersCur = db.O_MemberWhere(u => u.OrgId == member.OrgId && u.Manage == true && u.JoinedStored == true).ToList();
    List<string> curUserIds = ManagersCur.Select(u => u.UserId).ToList();

    //list of managers stored in userlist
    List<UserListItem> ManagersList = db.UserListItem.Where(u => u.UserListId == listId).ToList();
    List<string> listUserIds = ManagersList.Select(u => u.UserId).ToList();

    foreach (var curMgrId in curUserIds) {
        if (!listUserIds.Contains(curMgrId)) {
            var newUserLI = new UserListItem();
            newUserLI.UserListId = listId;
            newUserLI.UserId = curMgrId;
            db.UserListItem.Add(newUserLI);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```